# Can I change merging options on single files mid merge?

Tags: git

Okay say I've done `git merge production`. I've resolved a few issues but now I'd like to retry merging a specific file with `-Xignore-all-space`. My current strategy is to simply abort my merge, and restart it with `-Xignore-all-space`, is there some way I can change this mid merge?